# How to avoid calling implements at 2 activites?

Tags: java, android

I have two activities: `MainActivity extends ListActivity` and `Preferences implements BillingController.IConfiguration`.

Now I need to call `BillingController.someMethod(this)` at `MainActivity`. Such call can be made only if `MainActivity implements BillingController.IConfiguration`. But this is already implemented at `Preferences` class. What can I do to avoid implementing that again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a class that implements `BillingController.IConfiguration` and use it inside both `MainActivity` and `Preferences` to delegate method calls to it.

Answer (score 1):

Do an instance of check.

```
if (instance instanceof BillingController.IConfiguration) {
    ((BillingController.IConfiguration)instance).someMethod(this);
}
```